# Consulta base de datos MongoDB

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, subconsultas, nosql, mongoatlas

Tengo un archivo de datos en mongo con una coleccion llamada empleados de este tipo con más filas con otras personas:

```js
{
    "_id": { "ObjectId":"22bca54f967563323887d" },
    "apellidos": "Mez Fernández",
    "contrato": "Indefinido",
    "dni": "1234500Z",
    "direccion": {
        "cp": 5221,
        "localidad": "Llanes",
        "provincia": "Llobregat",
        "calle": "Calle gondo,375 2ºA"
    },
    "estado_civil": "Casado",
    "nombre": "Osvaldo",
    "num_hijos": 2,
    "salario": 21501,
    "telefono": 611611335
},
```

1.Si quisiera obtener la suma total del salario de todos los trabajadores como sería?

He intentado esto pero no funciona:

`db.empleados.aggregate([{suma:{$sum:"salario"}}])`

2.Como puedo aumentar en +2000 euros el salario a todos los trabajadores?

Debería usar aggregate en ambas?

Comment: Un proceso de agregación no modifica los datos, sólo los procesa para mostrarlos. Para modificar debes usar algún método `update`. Por otro lado, para obtener la suma del salario, puedes usar agregación, pero tal como lo haces no es correcto, ya que `suma` no es ninguna etapa de agregación válida, es el nombre del campo que estás tratando de crear con la suma del salario.

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por tu ayuda pero no me ha quedado claro como debería usar sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/452861/consulta-base-de-datos-mongodb#comment806730_452861), tu problema está en que usas el nombre de un campo (`suma`) como si fuese el nombre de una etapa de agregación. Creo que tienes una pequeña confusión entre lo que es una [agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) y lo que es una simple [operación (consulta)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/).

Deseas sumar el salario de todos los documentos registrados en la base de datos, un proceso de agregación lo hace en un pestañeo, pero debemos usar la [etapa](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) adecuada.

Por otro lado, deseas actualizar el valor del campo `salario` para todos los documentos de la colección, para ello debes usar una operación de [actualización (`update`)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/).

**SOLUCIÓN**

**Agregación**

La solución es sencilla, primero vamos a obtener la suma del salario de todos los documentos. Para ello usaremos una etapa [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) y pasaremos como argumento una expresión que involucra al *operador de agregación* [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/), y como campo `_id` de la agrupación usaremos `null`.

Una etapa de agregación no es lo mismo que un operador de agregación, por lo cual no son intercambiables. Con esto quiero decir que no puedes usar un operador de agregación como si fuese una etapa de agregación. Por lo tanto esto no está permitido:

```js
// ESTO ESTA MAL
const result = db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $sum: "$salario"  // <- ESTO NO ES VÁLIDO, $sum NO ES ETAPA, ES OPERADOR
    }
]);
```

Aclarado este punto, la forma correcta de realizar la agregación sería la siguiente:

```js
const result = db.empleados.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            suma: {
                $sum: "$salario"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Esto nos produce un resultado similar al siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "suma": 64209.649321108765
  }
]
```

Como se observa se agruparon todos los documentos bajo el mismo `_id` (`null`) y el resultado de la suma de todos los salarios se puede apreciar en el campo `suma`.

Si no deseamos devolver el campo `_id` que contiene `null`, podemos añadir una segunda etapa, esta vez usaremos una etapa [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) a la cual pasaremos un objeto que contiene lo siguiente:

```
{ "_id": 0 }
```

Esto indica que deseamos devolver todos los campos del documento excepto el campo `_id`. Y dado que nuestro documento sólo contiene 2 campos, al final sólo devolverá el campo `suma`. El código podría quedar así:

```js
db.empleados.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "suma": {
        "$sum": "$salario"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Recuerda que un proceso de agregación como este devuelve un `Array` con resultados, en este caso el `Array` contiene 1 documento.

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcional en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nd-1Vjbkoyp), en el que se han generado aleatoriamente 50 documentos en una colección, con el 10 por ciento de ellos sin campo `salario`.

Cuando un documento carece del campo sobre el cual estamos calculando la suma, el operador devuelve 0, continuando con el proceso de suma sin interrupciones.

**Actualización de documentos**

Para actualizar documentos se usa alguno de los métodos siguientes:

- [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update): Actualiza un documento (puede actualizar más de uno si se establece la opción `multi` a `true`).
- [`updateOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/): Actualiza un documento de acuerdo al filtro pasado como primer argumento, si no se provee filtro o el mismo es un objeto vacío, se actualizará el primer documento encontrado en la colección.
- [`updateMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/): actualiza todos los documentos que coincidan con el filtro, si no se provee un filtro o el mismo es un objeto vacío, se actualizarán todos los documentos de la colección.
- [`replaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/): Reemplaza el primer documento que coincida con el filtro, si no se provee filtro o el mismo es un objeto vacío, reemplaza el primer documento encontrado en la colección.

Como puedes apreciar, tienes opciones para escoger, y en el caso particular de tu pregunta, usaremos `updateMany()`.

***Atención***

Una operación de tipo `update`, reemplazará **todo** el documento con el valor pasado como segundo argumento. Esto puede ser un problema si no tenemos cuidado de usar un [operador de actualización](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#std-label-update-operators), por ejemplo [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/), de lo contrario el documento pasado como segundo argumento se asume como documento de reemplazo.

Esto significa que si tenemos el siguiente documento almacenado en la base de datos:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("60a68383820a87f9b736c0e2"),
  nombre: "Mauricio"
  apellidos: "Contreras Canepa"
  pais: "Venezuela"
}
```

Y deseamos actualizar este documento usando la siguiente consulta:

```js
db.usuarios.update({_id: ObjectId("60a68383820a87f9b736c0e2")}, {pais: "España"})
```

Podríamos pensar que ahora el documento contiene los mismos datos excepto que el campo `pais` ha cambiado de "Venezuela" a "España", pero lo cierto es que todo el documento (a excepción del campo `_id`) ha sido reemplazado por un documento cuyo único campo es `pais`, perdiéndose los campos `nombre` y `apellidos`.

Para que esto no ocurra usaremos el operador de actualización `$set`:

```js
db.usuarios.update(
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a68383820a87f9b736c0e2")
  },
  {
    $set: {
      pais: "España"
    }
  }
)
```

**`updateMany()`**

Ahora, para actualizar todos los documentos de la colección de tal manera que se *inc*rementa el valor del campo `salario`, usaremos `updateMany()` de la siguiente forma:

```js
db.empleados.updateMany({}, // <- documento filtro vacío, actualiza todos los registros
{
  "$inc": {
    "salario": 2000
  }
});
```

En esta consulta de actualización hemos usado el operador de actualización [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/), que realiza una operación de incremento (suma) sobre el campo especificado. Si deseamos restar (decremento) basta con pasar un valor negativo al operador `$inc`. (Recordemos que cuando usamos operadores de actualización, sólo se actualizan los campos indicados por el operador.)

En el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9HGX0-I14GR), puedes ver un ejemplo usando el método `update()` en donde se incrementa el valor de un campo y a la vez se disminuye el valor de otro campo.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias,muy bien explicado y con detalle,se agradece!